# How to call a partial view to display via URL?

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller, partial-views

I've tried a few ways of trying to get a loaded partial view being called on the same page with no success. I used AJAX but it didn't work (See this [AJAX request for a loaded partial view -MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29390190/ajax-request-for-a-loaded-partial-view-mvc))

I basically want a loaded partial view to display editable Job info to the user depending on the value they enter into the textbox.Is it possible to call and load the partial view via URL like the one below?

```
http://localhost:9171/Job/Edit/[Product ID]
```

Any ways on going about loading the partial view? ill provide any further information if needed.

I appreciate the help :)

Comment: Please update your question with what you have tried (you say you've tried a few ways). Also, I'm having a hard time understanding what it is you're asking (expected results). If you can be more clear, please be :)

Comment: updated Mackan :) I basically want a partial view to load showing the user and editable job details on the same page, im very new to ajax and partial views hence the lack of information :/

Comment: How far does the code get? I mean, when you change the textbox, will the ajax fire? Then does the controller action fire?

Comment: The ajax fires but as seen in the last question, I get an error from Google chrome, so it doesn't fire the controller. I presume its to do with my partial view or controller but I can't figure out what it is

Comment: I answered your other post, since it was more "on topic" there

Comment: Thanks @mackan :) I will try again in the morning and let you know how I get on :) I have to catch a flight here ha :) I appreciate the help

Comment: Resolved... see following question = http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29390190/ajax-request-for-a-loaded-partial-view-mvc